# How to implement a Gift Wrap option on shopping cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I have to implement a 'Gift Wrap Order' at shopping cart page.

**Calculation**

- If the sub-total is less than $50 it will charge a $5 for wrap.
- and if the sub-total is $50 or higher 'Gift Wrap' is free of charge.

**Requirement**

1. This option is available on shopping cart page.
2. Above calculation is for order subtotal.
3. No special wrapping paper selection needed just this check box.
4. If this option is enabled by the customer, it should notify with the order.

Can these requirements implement? If so can you suggest or guide me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: it about 3rd party extension,you need to put it details

Comment: Can you suggest a extension, which can achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In the admin, Go to Sale > Gift Wrapping
Select Add Gift Wrapping
Create a name for the wrapping, add price, upload image